# Pass "this" to a bootbox callback with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, bootbox

I'm using Backbone and bootbox.
This is my code inside a view:

```
    confirm : function(result) {
        if (result === true) { 
            var that = this;
            this.model.set({completed: '1'}); // Exception here
            this.model.save(
                    null, {
                success: function (model, response) {
                    Backbone.history.navigate("index", true);
                },
                error: function(model, response) {
                    that.model.set({completed: '0'});
                    var responseObj = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                    bootbox.alert(responseObj.message);
                }
            });
        }
    },

    completeProcess : function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.model.set({completed: '1'});
        bootbox.confirm("Confirm?", this.confirm );
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of undefined

Is there a way to pass the reference from the view?

Comment: Have you looked at [_.bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind)?

Comment: @Jack What's the value of `_.bind` over standard `Function.prototype.bind`? Backwards compatibility? I don't see anything else.

Comment: @JustinMorgan If the standard (or rather a *native*) `bind` is available underscore will use that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [underscore](/questions/tagged/underscore) is a dependency of [backbone](/questions/tagged/backbone) you could use its `_.bind` feature:

```
_.bind(function, object, [*arguments])
```

> Bind a function to an object, meaning that whenever the function is
>   called, the value of this will be the object.
>   Optionally, pass
>   arguments to the function to pre-fill them, also known as partial
>   application.

In your case this could look like this:

```
completeProcess : function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.model.set({completed: '1'});
  bootbox.confirm("Confirm?", _.bind(this.confirm, this));
}
```

Comment: a question: what about the original parameter "result" passed by bootbox? I mean, is it just ignored?

Comment: so I tried it but I'm still getting the result from the confirm and not the this reference. I need both.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do something like this to hang on to the original 'this':

```
var _this = this;

bootbox.confirm({
    message: Message ,
    callback: function(result) {
        console.log(this + " != " + _this);
    },
```